# ADF Mobile Secured SOAP webservice with custom Header

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

I'm trying to create an ADF Mobile Application that connects to a secure soap web service (username_token policy) and with extra added custom header.

I tried every thing in:

http://andrejusb.blogspot.ae/2012/11/adf-mobile-secured-web-service-access.html
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/accessing_secure_web_services_from
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/doc.111240/e24475/amxwebservices.htm#CHDGJJAD

All faild.

Note that i was able to use the WS through Jdeveloper Http Analyzer after adding the custom header elements.

and in ADF Mobile:
I extended the SOAPProvider class and modified the provider in DataControls.dcx
I Added the header elements as exactly worked from Http Analyzer but no luck.

When I deploy I get "Malformed response message" error ( i guess because the WS returns not xml formatted response when not adding required header elements"

Please not that i don't have any control on the WS and i can't change its security or custom header elements.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a similar usecase some days back. Here is the link:
http://stick2code.blogspot.in/2014/07/passing-custom-soap-headers-in-adf.html
Hope it helps!